# React Router v6 Not Found

Tags: react-router

I'm updating a project from React Router v5 to v6.  I have read up on things here and googled around a lot but can't understand why this routing isn't working.  I have this as my App.tsx component:

```
import React, {ReactElement, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MainContent from "./components/MainContent";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Navigate, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";
import {Routes} from "react-router";
import {PAGES, PATHS} from "./Constants";
import Door from "./pages/Door";
import Landing from "./pages/Landing";
import RequireAuth from "./components/RequireAuth";
import {pages} from "./pages/routes";
import TaskEdit from "./pages/TaskEdit";
import {PageTypes} from "./Enums";
import {IsPageAvailableToUser} from "./Utility";
import {ClientProvider} from "./clients/ClientProvider";

const authService = ClientProvider.AuthService;

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.REACT_APP_HEADER_TAG != null && process.env.REACT_APP_HEADER_TAG !== '') {
      document.title = `${process.env.REACT_APP_HEADER_TAG} | ${document.title}`;
    }
  }, []);

  function getPageContent(page: {
    path: string,
    title: string,
    uiVisible: boolean,
    component: ReactElement,
    exact: boolean,
    type: PageTypes,
  }): any {
    switch (page.type) {
      case PageTypes.protected:
      case PageTypes.customers:
      case PageTypes.usage:
      case PageTypes.settings:
        if (!IsPageAvailableToUser(page, authService.CurrentUser)) {
          return undefined;
        }

        return <Route
          key={page.path}
          path={page.path}
          element={<RequireAuth>{page.component}</RequireAuth>}
        />;
      case PageTypes.auth:
        return undefined;
    }
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={PATHS[PAGES.ROOT]} element={<RequireAuth><MainContent/></RequireAuth>}>
          {pages.map(page => getPageContent(page))}
          <Route key={'/tasks/edit'}
                 path={`tasks/:id/:action?`}
                 element={<RequireAuth><TaskEdit/></RequireAuth>}/>
          <Route path={''} element={<Navigate to={`${PATHS[PAGES.ROOT]}${PATHS[PAGES.TASK]}`}/>}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path={PATHS[PAGES.DOOR]} element={<Door/>}/>
        <Route path={`${PATHS[PAGES.LANDING]}`} element={<Landing/>}/>
        <Route path={''} element={<Navigate to={PATHS[PAGES.DOOR]} replace/>}/>
        <Route key={'catch'} path='*' element={<NotFound/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

RequireAuth looks like this:

```
import React, {ReactElement} from 'react';
import {useLocation} from "react-router";
import {pages} from "../pages/routes";
import {PAGES, PATHS} from "../Constants";
import {IsPageAvailableToUser} from "../Utility";
import {ClientProvider} from "../clients/ClientProvider";
import {Navigate} from "react-router-dom";

const authService = ClientProvider.AuthService;

const RequireAuth = ({children}: { children: ReactElement | undefined }) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const page = pages.find(p => `${PATHS[PAGES.ROOT]}${p.path}` === location.pathname);
  const hasAccess = authService.IsLoggedIn
    && (page == null || IsPageAvailableToUser(page, authService.CurrentUser));

  return hasAccess
    ? children
    : <Navigate to={{pathname: PATHS[PAGES.DOOR]}}
                state={{from: authService.IsLoggedIn ? undefined : location}} replace/>;
};

export default RequireAuth;
```

and MainContent looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Outlet} from 'react-router';
import HeaderBar from "./HeaderBar";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {FlexRow} from "../CommonStyledComponents";
import Theme from "@adsk/alloy-react-theme";
import Divider from "@adsk/alloy-react-divider";

const AppContainer = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const MainContainer = styled(FlexRow)`
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
`;

const ContentContainer = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex;
`;

const MainContent = () => {
  return (
    <AppContainer style={Theme.typography.bodyMedium}>
      <HeaderBar/>
      <Divider/>
      <MainContainer>
        <Nav/>
        <ContentContainer>
          <Outlet />
        </ContentContainer>
      </MainContainer>
    </AppContainer>
  );
};

export default MainContent;
```

the `pages` variable is defined as an array of page objects defined like this (only giving one for brevity but others are the same):

```
  {
    path: PATHS[PAGES.TASK],
    component: <Tasks/>,
    title: PAGE_TITLES[PAGES.TASK],
    exact: true,
    renderIcon: (p: any) => <TaskListIcon {...p} />,
    uiVisible: true,
    type: PageTypes.protected,
  },
```

and lastly, the path definition for tasks is `[PAGES.TASK]: "/tasks"`

When I start this app and go to localhost:3000 it goes to the door properly, gets the auth, then redirects to `/app/tasks`, which should be right.  However, the rendered output is the `<NotFound />` component.  The primary route (where `MainContent` is) should be under it's path (`/app`) so child components should be relative I believe which would make the tasks page `/app/tasks` right?  Just in case, I also tried `/tasks` by itself but same result, not found.

Comment: I don't see any `"/app/tasks"` route being rendered in your code example, so the `"*"` catch-all route matching makes sense to me.

Comment: The very first route is `/app` but then it has children defined by the mapped pages items.  One of those is tasks that has a path of `/tasks`  shouldn't that be relative and end up as `/app/tasks`?  Or am I missing something there?

Comment: Can you [edit] with a simpler and more concrete [mcve] so we're not left guessing what values some of these variables have?

Comment: Ok I'll work on it.

Comment: Ok disregard, sorry.  In trying to simplify and reproduce I figured out that my call to `IsPageAvailableToUser` was returning false in all cases because it was not logged in yet, so it never created those routes.  Previously that was at lower levels when the user was already logged in so returned the paths correctly. Once I removed it from the app level and just left it at the protected path level it worked.  Sorry about that, thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: No worries at all. It's often the case that when you are conditionally rendering routes you may run into synchronicity issues trying to navigate to them before the routes have loaded/rendered. If the tasks paths are largely the same except for a task id or similar it may be better to render a single dynamic route, e.g. `"/tasks/:taskId"` than it would be to try and render a discrete static route for each. Cheers and good luck though.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes this makes more sense now anyway, it's rendering all routes but the auth protection just determines if the current user can get to it or not, that way auth validation is encapsulated too.  Just took me a bit to get there :)